# Can java.util.Calendar be passed over method?

Tags: java

this is my code:

```
import java.util.Calendar;

import java.util.Locale;

public class test {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Calendar a = Calendar.getInstance();
        a.set(Calendar.MONTH, 7);
        a.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2011);
        a.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 16);

        System.out.print(test.getDate(a));
    }

    // What-date calculation
    public static String getDate(Calendar date) {
        //date = Calendar.getInstance();
        return date.getDisplayName(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.LONG,
                Locale.getDefault());
    }

}
```

when I run this code, it prints "Tuesday". However, I run this code on July 16, 2011 and uncomment

```
date = Calendar.getInstance();
```

so that `date` would be July 16, 2011 and it prints exactly "Saturday".

I wonder if the Calendar object `a` is passed correctly because `a` is also set July 16, 2011.
Is there any solution for me to pass Calendar object and print the date correctly?

Thank in advance

Comment: anything can be passed, as long you have the reference or the value.

Comment: @LxL make sure to mark as accepted the answer that worked for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use "magic" numbers when setting Calendar's month since they are 0 based (not 1 based as you have assumed). Instead use the Calendar constants, such as Calendar.JULY.

Comment: I see, thank you. Because I'm using Android document and it didn't mention this issue the month issue.

Comment: @LxL: whether you are using Android or not is moot since regardless, you are using java.util.Calendar, and for this class the documentation in the API is quite clear.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels: I concur with you because it use the same lib.
but the point is in Android docs [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#MONTH) it doesn't mention as the java official doc Bozho gave:D

Answer (score 3):

`MONTH` is zero-based. So 7 is August. See [the docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#MONTH). There is `Calendar.JULY` for your convenience

Answer (score 2):

That's easy - Calendar doesn't use 1-indexed months. You're setting it to August 16th. Print the toString() of the Calendar object and you'll see. Calendar provides constants that you can use as well.

You may want to check out the Joda DateTime library, which lets you use 1-indexed months more easily and solves a number of other calendaring problems.